# Next JS: unable to use scss on Windows

Tags: sass, next.js

I am building a Next JS application. To admit, this is my first exposure to Next JS. Now, I am having a problem using SCSS with my Next JS application. I have created a file called, assets/auth.scss. Then I imported it into pages/_app.js as follow.

```
import '../assets/auth.scss';
```

When I run "npm run dev", I am getting the following error.

```
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/nex
t/dist/compiled/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[4]!./assets/auth.scss
Error: Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\shar-kya-mal-next-js\nextjs-blog\.next\build-manifest.json'
Require stack:
```

Then I tried installing node-sass package too. It still does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-next-sass

Comment: You have to install [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) not `node-sass`. Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support You are getting such error because you've probably installed the latest version of node-sass, which is shadowing the required version. Uninstall it from your project, then follow the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use npm install sass or node sass? Every next project where i will use scss i use npm install sass and it works normally. Do you do something different?
Try to use npm install sass or yarn install sass